# How can I add a constant percentage to each wedge of a pie chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Code snippet looks like this

```
#df is dataframe with 6 rows, with each row index being the label of the sector
plt.pie(df.iloc[:,0], labels= df.index) #plot the first column of dataframe as a pie chart
```

It generates a pie chart like this:

[Pie Chart with the 6 sectors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9PXx.png)

As you can see, the sectors kitchen & entertainment are very small. I want to make each sector have a minimum value of 10 degree (1/36 %).

This would effectively mean fitting the data over 300 degrees (10 degree to each sector and we have 6 - Lighting, Entertainment, Kitchen, Cooling, Fridge, Others)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Imagine a case where you have used a non-linear regression to find coefficients. Some will be negative and others positive. But when this is a model for where you are sure all of them must be positive (such as energy consumption, money spent, etc), you can add a constant weight to those terms. This is related to that. I just wanted to assign a constant minimum weight for the factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make each sector have a minimum value of 10 degree

Solving this for the general case is difficult and requires further definition. This introduces a skew into the results, and to decide between different algorithms, you'd need to specify a metric defining how close is some skewed result to the original.

However, there is a very simple thing you can do which will guarantee your requirement. Say the length of your DataFrame is *n*, the sum of its elements is *s*, and you want the result to have no less than *α* (in your case, *α = 1./36*). If you would simply add some *x* to all elements, then the new sum would be

*s + nx*

Assuming that no element is negative, the smallest element would have weight at least *x / (s + nx)*.

Solving for

*x / (s + nx) = α*

Gives

*x = s α / (1 - αn)*.

So, if the Series you wish to pie-chart is `df.a`, you could do

```
x = max(df.a.sum() * alpha / (1 - alpha * len(df)), 0)
```

and then plot instead `df.a + x`.

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 40, 40, 50, 50, 500]})

x = max(df.a.sum() * alpha / (1 - alpha * len(df)), 0)
```

You can check the smallest relative weight of `df.a + x`

```
(df.a + x).min() / (df.a + x).sum()
```

is indeed greater than *α*.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : This is my own question.

What [Ami Tavory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510736/ami-tavory) has answered is the correct approach. I was thinking it from the perspective of plotting (fitting the data to 300 degrees instead of 360) instead of manipulating the data (which is much simpler, thanks to pandas).

I am just posting a much simpler form of his answer:

```
degree = 10 #The degree you want to offset each sector with
# Let the number of sectors be N

plt.pie((df.iloc[:,0]*((360 - degree*N)/360) + ((degree * df.iloc[:,0].sum())/360)), labels= df.index)

#The above is simply scaling the data to fit 300 (degree = 10, N = 6)
# and adding a constant value of degree/360 of the total sum to each sector.
```